# The use of Joyo Kanji in names

Tags: names

I know that Jinmeiyo Kanji are used in names, but can some Joyo Kanji be used as well?

For example, on Jisho, I found 夜{ゆみ} being used as a name though it is not a Jinmeiyo Kanji, although it is a Grade 4 Joyo Kanji. The same goes for 愛{ゆき}, which is only a Grade 2 Kanji.

Can anyone explain this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Legal characters for first names include: hiragana, katakana, jinmeiyo and joyo kanji. What about latin letters?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11937/legal-characters-for-first-names-include-hiragana-katakana-jinmeiyo-and-joyo)

Comment: *All* jouyou Kanji are permissible for use in names.

Comment: If the answers on the dupe target don't apply here, we can't close this as a duplicate.  The sole answer on that question doesn't address whether the jōyō kanji can be used for names, so I'm voting to Leave Open.

Answer (score 2):

Of course they can be used in names. The 人名用 kanzi are just ones that are not 常用 but that are still good to know for (at least) the purposes of recognizing and using them in names. It just depends on the person and the name. Some examples of common 常用漢字 names:

- 浜野
- 本田
- 松本
- 石川
- 太郎
- 中村
- 高橋
- 雪子

Some of these examples are last names and some are first names. Notice that most are composed of two characters.

Note that there can be 常用 and 表外 ways to write names (or even numerous ways of writing names in either different 常用 or 表外漢字). For example, 濱野 is another name pronounced はまの. Names are also not limited to 漢字, for example, depending on the parents' preference when deciding a first name (even if the name could be written in 漢字). However, the same person always writes their name the same way.